# Parsing data with elementtree into a dictionary/list

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm working with Elementtree to parse an XML file (Nessus data). Ive identified the item.attrib which looks to be a dictionary with a `'name': 'IPaddress'`. I'd like to add this data into a dictionary, or if I can access just the ipaddress into a list. How can I access the value for `name` only? Ive tried using variations on item[0]/[1]/.attrib/text/ but still no luck.

**Current Code**

```
import elementtree.ElementTree as ET

def getDetails(nessus_file):
    host_list = []
    host_dict = {}
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(nessus_file)
        doc = tree.getroot()
        reporthost = doc.getiterator('ReportHost')
        for child in doc:
            if child.tag == 'Report':
                for item in child:
                    if item.tag == 'ReportHost':
                        print item.attrib

    except Exception as e:
        print e
        exit()
getDetails('file.nessus')
```

**Example Output From Current Code**

```
{'name': '172.121.26.80'}
{'name': '172.121.26.42'}
{'name': '172.121.26.41'}
{'name': '172.121.26.21'}
{'name': '172.121.26.15'}
{'name': '172.121.26.14'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `item.get('name')`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get for details.

Comment: Arr thanks Bernard. I didnt realise item had a get method. My IDE doesnt give me any values to choose for 'item.'.